# How can I check if the arrow keys have been pressed in Ruby and Windows Console

Tags: ruby, windows

I am using Ruby 2.1.5 and Windows Console.  I need to be able to scan for key presses with out stopping execution.  I need to be able to detect the arrow keys specifically.  I have tried numerous methods recommend on other questions but none of them work on the windows console or do not detect the arrow keys.

**Does not show arrow keys**

```
require 'io/console'
loop do
  p STDIN.getch
end
```

**Runs with out errors but does not appear to read from input buffer because all the keys pressed show on the console after program is exited using Ctrl-C**

```
require 'io/wait'

def char_if_pressed
  begin

    system("stty raw -echo") # turn raw input on
    c = nil
    if $stdin.ready?
      c = $stdin.getc
    end
    c.chr if c
  ensure
      system "stty -raw echo" # turn raw input off
  end
end

while true
  c = char_if_pressed
  puts "[#{c}]" if c
  sleep 1
  puts "tick"
end
```

**This one also runs with out errors but requires the enter key to be pressed before it will continue to run. I need non-blocking input**

```
# read a character without pressing enter and without printing to the screen
def read_char
  begin
    # save previous state of stty
    old_state = "stty raw -g"
    # disable echoing and enable raw (not having to press enter)
    system "stty raw -echo"
    c = STDIN.getc.chr
    # gather next two characters of special keys
    if(c=="\e")
      puts "checking for non alpha"
      extra_thread = Thread.new{
        c = c + STDIN.getc.chr
        c = c + STDIN.getc.chr
      }
      # wait just long enough for special keys to get swallowed
      extra_thread.join(0.00001)
      # kill thread so not-so-long special keys don't wait on getc
      extra_thread.kill
    end
  rescue => ex
    puts "#{ex.class}: #{ex.message}"
    puts ex.backtrace
  ensure
    # restore previous state of stty
    system "stty #{old_state}"
  end
  return c
end

# takes a single character command
def show_single_key
  c = read_char
  case c
    when " "
      puts "SPACE"
    when "\t"
      puts "TAB"
    when "\r"
      puts "RETURN"
    when "\n"
      puts "LINE FEED"
    when "\e"
      puts "ESCAPE"
    when "\e[A"
      puts "UP ARROW"
    when "\e[B"
      puts "DOWN ARROW"
    when "\e[C"
      puts "RIGHT ARROW"
    when "\e[D"
      puts "LEFT ARROW"
    when "\177"
      puts "BACKSPACE"
    when "\004"
      puts "DELETE"
    when /^.$/
      puts "SINGLE CHAR HIT: #{c.inspect}"
    else
      puts "SOMETHING ELSE: #{c.inspect}"
  end
end
show_single_key while(true)
```

**This appears to be a variation of the last one that works correctly for all the ASCII represented keys but does not work for the arrow keys and has an issue with enter.**

```
require 'io/console'

# Reads keypresses from the user including 2 and 3 escape character sequences.
def read_char
  STDIN.echo = false
  STDIN.raw!

  input = STDIN.getc.chr
  puts input
  if input == "\e" then
    puts "getting additional characters"
    input << STDIN.read_nonblock(3) rescue nil
    input << STDIN.read_nonblock(2) rescue nil
  end
ensure
  #STDIN.echo = true
  STDIN.cooked!

  return input
end

# oringal case statement from:
# http://www.alecjacobson.com/weblog/?p=75
def show_single_key
  c = read_char

  case c
  when " "
    puts "SPACE"
  when "\t"
    puts "TAB"
  when "\r"
    puts "RETURN"
  when "\n"
    puts "LINE FEED"
  when "\e"
    puts "ESCAPE"
  when "\e[A"
    puts "UP ARROW"
  when "\e[B"
    puts "DOWN ARROW"
  when "\e[C"
    puts "RIGHT ARROW"
  when "\e[D"
    puts "LEFT ARROW"
  when "\177"
    puts "BACKSPACE"
  when "\004"
    puts "DELETE"
  when "\e[3~"
    puts "ALTERNATE DELETE"
  when "\u0003"
    puts "CONTROL-C"
    exit 0
  when /^.$/
    puts "SINGLE CHAR HIT: #{c.inspect}"
  else
    puts "SOMETHING ELSE: #{c.inspect}"
  end
end

show_single_key while(true)
```

I also tried a couple that had Win32API calls but they both failed to work properly and had warnings about being deprecated. I would like a cross platform solution but at this point I will settle for it working correctly on a windows console.  Also I can not use any Ruby Gems for this.

Comment: No Ruby experts ever encountered this before?

Comment: Why can't you use gems? That seems like an awfully restrictive, arbitrary condition. The proper way to do this is using a curses library. There are plenty of gems that provide wrappers for such libraries, but I guess you're going to have to write such a wrapper yourself. From scratch. For no reason.

Comment: Sometimes you have to work with restrictive arbitrary conditions.  I will not have access to the machine this code will be run on and will not be able to install any Ruby Gems to it.  If there is a way to include the functions of a Gem and send them along with my code without that Gem being installed on the other machine I would be happy to use them.  I am a bit new to Ruby but doesn't a gem have to be on every computer your program is run on or is there a way to "compile" your ruby code to where it will run on every machine that has the ruby interpreter regardless of the gems they have?

Comment: A gem is just a collection of Ruby code for you to `require`. Even if you can't properly install gems with a package manager, there's nothing stopping you from downloading the gem manually and including its files alongside your script.

Comment: How would I do that for curses?

Comment: The process should be the same for any gem. Install the gem, copy its files out of the installation directory to the directory of your Ruby script.

Comment: How would I include them in my script?  Does the require command look in the local directory too or is there an import or include function I need to use?

Comment: `require` can take an absolute or relative path if you don't want it to use Ruby's library search path. It might be easier to just modify Ruby's load path to search your directory first.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to solve this issue for a little while and this worked for me:

```
require 'io/console'
while true
    user_input = $stdin.getch         
    case user_input
    when 'q'
        exit
    when '['        
        print '' # I believe that by entering this block of code user_input drops the first char. What is left can be used to determine what key has been pressed.  
    else
        case user_input  
        when 'A'
            puts "up"
        when 'B'
            puts "down"
        when 'C'
            puts "right"
        when 'D'
            puts "left"
        end
    end
end
```

I'm using ruby 2.4.1. Hope it helps.